# How to use Appium to interact with an element that remains visible on the UI for 2-3 seconds?

Tags: automation, notifications, appium-android, appium-ios

I need to tap on an element that hardly stays for 3 seconds on the UI. Since it is vanishing from the UI within 3 seconds, my test is getting failed while finding the element. Is there a way to deal with it using appium?

**Scenario** -

1. User1 generates a notification for User2
2. User2 needs to find the element and tap on it